# jQuery nested selector is not working but find() is working fine

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'location': 'New York, NYC' },
    success: function(listings) {
        jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']").each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).find("h2").text(listings[index].name);
        });
    }});

</script>
```

on page: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Its working fine.

I select all `DIV` with `id=clinic_name` and then select `h2` tag in it and change its inner text.

The main line is:

```
jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']").each(function(index) {
                jQuery(this).find("h2").text(listings[index].name);
```

Its working fine.

But if I try:

```
jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" > h2).each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).text(listings[index].name);
```

It doesn't work. I was trying to select `h2` directly in the `DIV` selector. Am I not writing `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" > h2)` selector properly?

I think its better to select the h2 tag in the main DIV selector. Can it be done?

Comment: `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" > h2)`  => `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name'] > h2")` or `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name'] h2")`

Comment: The `>` selector means that the `h2` has to be a child of the `div`. Using `find()` means the `h2` can be at any level *below* the `div`, so child, grandchild, great-grandchild  etc. ***However*** you imply there are multiple elements with the id of `clinic_name`. That is a big red flag and needs to be fixed. Use a common class on multiple elements to group them, not ids, as they need to be unique within the DOM. Then your code becomes `$('.clinic_name h2').text(function(i) { return listings[i].name; });`

Comment: can I use class to select? I can either set ID or Class for any element in my page. Can I select h2 at any level / depth in main DIV selector?

Comment: @PranavCBalan ok. Thanks. jQuery("div[id='clinic_name'] h2") worked but jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" > h2) didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your selector and not jquery,

The `>` means only direct descendants, i.e immediate children,

So instead of `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" > h2)` you should have `jQuery("div[id='clinic_name']" h2)`

FYI, ID's are supposed to be unique. Also `div#clinic_name` will be faster than `div[id='clinic_name']`